# how do I run Rails 3.2 in production on my mac w/o getting cache: [GET /] miss

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this app running in development just right, but when I deploy the bugger, everything starts falling apart :(

So I tried grabbing the log while running development on my Mac - and then the exact thing, on the exact same platform (just switching from development to production environment). I believe to have not been messing with config/application.rb, config/environment.rb or config/environments/*

I've saved the screen output here: https://gist.github.com/1692260

Really could do with a helping hand - as this is baffling me :(

Comment: Your development server probably doesn't have caching turned on, so every request is effectively a cache miss. In production, it just tells you when it's a miss. But what's the problem?

Comment: What server software are you using? nginx/apache or are you using heroku/engine yard or anything else?

Comment: @RobDavis the problem is that css and js is not 'served' which leaves my responses a tad bland :( To me it seems like working in reverse: WEBrick reporting what is missed (hence not served) - but as I tried to add to the gist: the necessary files are in place (after I did my chores = rake assets:precompile

Comment: @Godisemo On my Mac - Webrick (and I've tried nginx+passenger to exact same result). On Linux (vmware virtualized FC16 on IBM M3 metal btw) I mostly use apache+passenger, but on this one, I've tried both flavors (nginx+passenger and apache+passenger)

Comment: have you tried setting config.serve_static_assets = true in production.rb?

Comment: @Godisemo I'm totally at a loss here! Results=perfect - but wouldn't I entirely miss the point of asset pipes, serving static assets in production? Could you help me see through this?

Comment: It depends on the server you are using. Webbrick cannot serve static files. This is why you must have rails do it. If you use apache or nginx, they could serve the static files for you. But that requires some configuration. I'll write these comments as an answer so others can see this question is (almost) solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing to

```
config.serve_static_assets = true in production.rb
```

in `production.rb`?

Webbrick cannot serve static files. This is why you must have rails do it. If you use apache or nginx, they could serve the static files for you. But that requires some configuration.

You can find information on how to configure Apache and Nginx [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production).

Comment: I'll accept the answer - even though I'm not sure it really is _the_ answer :)
Does this config nullify the asset pipe? Or is something missing in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)? Perhaps - I hope - when I know the answer, I'll return and update this question/answer
- but thanks for sharing, Godisemo!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error then realized my assets weren't compiled in production... I'd recommend trying

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

unless you know your stuff is being compiled. It slipped my mind because I'm so used to deploying to Heroku. This of course could only be the case in Rails >= 3.1

Comment: you might be rigth - but as the gist shows (right at the bottom) the css and js compiled elements 'should' be in place.